# Change a value in xaml with code in .cs (C#, Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have the following Code in the XAML:

```
<ht:BindableTranslateManipulator Direction="1 0 0"  Length="5" Diameter="1" Color="Black" 
                    Value="{Binding Variable}"
                    TargetTransform="{Binding Transform, ElementName=model1}"/>
                    <ht:FileModelVisual3D x:Name="model1" Source="C:\Users\SirBen\Downloads\helixtoolkit\helixtoolkit_27536c46993c\Source\Examples\ExampleBrowser\Cap.3ds"/>
```

Now i would like to change and repeadedly update the value of "Variable" through coding in .cs .

How can I do this? Is there not something as simple as `Variable.value("Value");`?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `DependencyProperty` and keep the binding as you have it. I assume it is an integer value you want to bind to

```
public int Variable
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(VariableProperty); }
    set { SetValue(VariableProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Variable.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty VariableProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Variable", typeof(int), typeof(ownerclass), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

In the codebehind file, you can just manipulate the value of `Variable` as you would a normal property